# Android - How to run several void() sequentially

Tags: android, arrays, json, void

I have an array with several Webservices that will send to the app json. I run through the array and call the web service, call a void() for this type of information, get the json, process it and go to the next array entry.

This works fine when the array has only one entry. But having more than one, it seams that the void()'s are running in parallel, conflicting the ProcessDialog (the same for all void()s).

What can I do that the void()s are running one after the other, that the app waits until one void is finished before going on to get the next entry from the array?

```
            try {
                JSONObject o = new JSONObject(strResponse);
                String strVersion = o.getString("version");
                JSONArray jsArray = null;
                jsArray = o.getJSONArray("tblWS");
                for(int i = 0; i < jsArray.length(); i++){
                    String strWS = jsArray.getString(i);

                    if (strWS.equals("WService1"))
                    {
                                downloadWService1();
                    }
                    if (strWS.equals("WService2"))
                    {
                                downloadWService2();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It looks for as as downloadWService1 and downloadWService 2 are running in parallel, but I want first that finishes downloadWService1 and when finished that starts downloadWService 2 ....

Comment: I think you'll have to show us an example of your code to clarify for us what you're doing.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code I assume your void functions are async tasks (since they are running in parallel). Why not make an list of bools (initiated as false), 1 bool per async task, and as long as bools[n-1] isnt true (task[n-1] sets it to true), task[n] will just remain idle.

Comment: tried it, but the negative effect is that the ProgressDialog is not shown, as the Loop is too fast.